# abnormality in the output of my code

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read an array in c++, filled with values from 0 to 5, For an unimportant reason, I need to count how many numbers 1, numbers 2, numbers 3, numbers 4 and numbers 5 do stand on the 'iii*DAYS'th position, so when iii = 0 and DAYS is 5, I need to know how many numbers 1, numbers 2, numbers 3, numbers 4 and numbers 5 are located on the 0th, 4th, 9th, 14th position. The code I posted does this quite well, but sometimes, gives a very big unlogical value, -36589245 or 99653256, can somebody tell me why this happens ( it does happen +- one in a hunderd times )

```
DAYS = 28
NURSES = 33
SHIFTS =5

int calculate_penalty_coverage_offspring(int offspring[NURSES*DAYS])
{
    int temporary[DAYS];
    int count[DAYS][SHIFTS];
    penalty_score_offspring_coverage =0;

        for (int ii = 0; ii<DAYS; ii++) 
        {
            int een  = 0;
            int twee = 0;
            int drie = 0;
            int vier = 0;
            int vijf = 0;
            for (int iii = 0; iii<NURSES; iii++)
            {
                temporary[iii] = offspring[(ii+(iii*DAYS))];
            }
            for(int a = 0 ; a<DAYS ; a++)
            {

                if(temporary[a]== 1)
                {
                    een++;
                    count[ii][0] = een;
                }
                else if(temporary[a] == 2)
                {
                    twee++;
                    count[ii][1] = twee;
                }
                else if(temporary[a]== 3)
                {
                    drie++;
                    count[ii][2] = drie;
                }
                else if(temporary[a]== 4)
                {
                    vier++;
                    count[ii][3] = vier;
                }
                else if(temporary[a] == 5)
                {
                    vijf++;
                    count[ii][4] = vijf;
                }   
            }
        }

        for(int ii = 0; ii<DAYS ; ii++)
        {
            for (int iii =0 ; iii<SHIFTS ; iii++)
            {
                cout << count[ii][iii] << '\t';
            }
            cout << '\n';
        }
```

this is the exeptional output where I talked about, as you can see, there is an onlogical value in the output of -31427696 ... I can't see why the function is working good, except for this one time.

```
1   2   2   4   4   
    5   2   2   9   5   
    9   6   3   5   2   
    8   3   4   3   8   
    9   3   3   4   6   
    5   5   6   8   1   
    6   8   2   2   5   
    3   5   8   -31427696   7   
    5   5   2   5   8   
    5   7   8   2   3   
    2   7   1   2   10  
    5   6   3   5   5   
    4   4   4   6   7   
    7   4   6   4   6   
    6   5   6   4   3   
    5   3   7   4   6   
    5   5   6   1   7   
    5   5   1   6   2   
    4   6   6   4   5   
    3   3   4   5   9   
    6   6   5   4   4   
    5   5   4   4   5   
    8   4   4   5   3   
    5   5   4   7   5   
    4   8   6   3   3   
    9   1   5   7   3   
    3   7   5   2   5   
    2   6   5   7   5
```

Comment: Could you share your Macros with values please,DAYS,NURSES etc..

Comment: `count[ii][temporary[a] - 1]++` And you get rid of all those `if / else`es and all those variables.

Comment: nullpointer , I did add them

Comment: `temporary[iii] = offspring[(ii+(iii*DAYS))]` is spoiling it...+ optimize as siggested by @bolov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you say

```
int temporary[DAYS];
```

Where

```
DAYS = 28
```

Then you do:

```
for (int iii = 0; iii<NURSES; iii++)
{
    temporary[iii] = offspring[(ii+(iii*DAYS))];
}
```

Where

```
NURSES = 33
```

You're trying to access indices that are out of bounds in `temporary`.

EDIT: Following our discussion in the comments,

You're additionally not initializing your arrays, specifically `count`:

```
int count[DAYS][SHIFTS];
```

Which you then *conditionally* fill in (partially) later:

```
if(temporary[a]== 1)
{
   een++;
   count[ii][0] = een;
}
// ...
```

Accesses to `count` afterwards to indices that were *not* assigned to will result in the garbage numbers you're seeing. You should probably just default the matrix to all zeros like so:

```
int count[DAYS][SHIFTS] = {0};
```

Comment: true, I changed the size of temporary to NURSES, but I still have the same problem ...

Comment: @StudentX: Is there a reason you say  `for(int a = 0 ; a<DAYS ; a++)
            {

                if(temporary[a]== 1)` when in fact `temporary` has a much larger size than `DAYS`? That is, you only ever access the first five elements in `temporary`.

Comment: AndyG ; I adjusted the code to this;'int temporary[NURSES];
 int count[DAYS][SHIFTS];
 penalty_score_offspring_coverage =0;
  
  for (int ii = 0; ii<DAYS; ii++) 
  {
   for (int iii = 0; iii<NURSES; iii++)
   {
    temporary[iii] = offspring[(ii+(iii*DAYS))];
   }
   for(int a = 0 ; a<NURSES ; a++)
   { 
    (count[ii][temporary[a] - 1])++;
   }
  }'

Comment: @StudentX: I can't really read that, but is there a reason for the checks like `if(temporary[a]== 1)`? Why not simply assign `count[ii][0] = een;`? I guess what I'm saying is, is it possible that one of those branches may not be taken? If they're not ALL taken, then `count` has uninitialized data after the loop, and accesses to such data will give you the garbage numbers you are seeing.

Comment: The values in the temporary array can be 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Every time a 1 occurs, the value in count[ii][0] should be done +1, if a 2 occurs, the value in count[ii][1] shoud be done +1, and so on .. Do you mean that I should als make a if(temporary[a] == 0 ?

Comment: @StudentX I mean that declaring `int count[DAYS][SHIFTS];` doesn't initialize the values to zero, they remain uninitialized until you set them. And it's possible that you may not set them.

Comment: how can I set these values to zero when the function starts ? int count[DAYS][SHIFTS] = NULL ?

Comment: @StudentX `int count[DAYS][SHIFTS]{0};` will do the trick: Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0265aca2b5197725

Comment: `int count[DAYS][SHIFTS] = {0};` If you're not using C++11 or higher

Comment: @StudentX: I've edited my answer. Please accept it if it solved your problem.